A CSP-related issue in react application
Please look into the below steps that followed

Created application using create-react-app

For validating CSP used the ZAP tool, and got the below alerts
enter image description here

Above calls, we are not doing this from our application, it might be React Engine is calling these calls/API(s) internally.

Added the below code in the app.js file
enter image description here


we tried to append a response header to resolve the above ZAP tool issues but in the console getting an error “Error: TypeError: Failed to execute 'set' on 'Headers': Headers are immutable.” in the above code while sending a request set the header tried to set the same headers in response
Could you please anyone provide a solution to resolve this CSP-related issue?.
